# Creating a split proportional/graduated symbol map in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am currently trying to make a split graduated/proportional symbol map on Classical music composers by country and musical era and I am having trouble with making the symbol in QGIS. I had to make a .csv table consisting of the totals by country and by era, and I am able to join my this table to a shape file of European countries, but the desired column (totals, representing the total composers of each country from the entire span of all musical eras) from the joined table I want to show represent with the graduated symbol does not show up in the drop down bar on either program.

I am able to get the split symbol using the pie graph feature on QGIS, but I still would like to be able to represent size changes of each pie graph showing the total composers from all eras.

Comment: Please decide, which software you want to work with. Also, since we don't know what exactly you did and which values your column holds, as well as how you are trying to create the graduate symbols or how your final output should look like. Please provide additional information, thank you.

Comment: You seem to have asked  the same question again using a different user identity.  see https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for help on how to merge your accounts.